# unsupported data type XML output with Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to export xml file from Oracle APEX with blob datatype from shared component > report queries. but the xml file has shown unsupported data type for blob column.

[image: UNSUPPORTED_DATATYPE]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried converting blob to clob before outputtung it?
Here's a link on how to do it:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_clob_script.htm

Comment: when I conver blob to clob, this code has been generated,and  it does not seem OK. "below comment"

Comment: ےغ Cےہ  M P" ےؤ            
ےؤ µ   } !1AQa"q2پ‘،#B±ءRرً$3br‚ 
%&amp;'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰ٹ’“”•–—ک™ڑ¢£¤¥¦§¨©ھ

Comment: What you have now is the textual representation of your blob, which according the name of the tag 'LOGO' seems to be an image, what is expected to be stored in this tag?